# How do I create a list of objects in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I started Kotlin after Java.

I want to write a function to return `Single<List<LocationData>>`

```
override fun getDestinations(): Single<List<LocationData>> {
  //return ???
}
```

My `LocationData` class:

```
@Parcelize
data class LocationData(val latitude: Double, val longitude: Double) : Parcelable
```

How can I create a `List` of static `LocationData` objects in Kotlin?

In Java I would do this like this:

```java
public ArrayList<LocationData> getDestinations(){
  ArrayList<LocationData> data = new ArrayList<>();
  LocationData location1 = new LocationData( 43.21123, 32.67643 );
  LocationData location2 = new LocationData( 32.67643, 43.21123 );
  data.add( location1 );
  data.add( location2 );
  return data;
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Kotlin, but [this search](/search?q=%5Bkotlin%5D+create+list+of+objects) turns up several questions with answers that seem to create lists of objects...

Comment: Note that you can always do it in a similar way to Java; if you can't see how, try putting the Java code into IntelliJ and running its Java-to-Kotlin converter.  However, that's not as short, simple, or safe as the Kotlin-specific approaches in the answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The most basic way is to use the [`listOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) function (or [`mutableListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html), if you need  to modify the list later):

```
fun getDestinations() = listOf( LocationData( 43.21123, 32.67643 ), LocationData( 32.67643, 43.21123 ))
```

Answer (score 5):

In Kotlin it will look like that:

```
fun getDestinations(): List<LocationData> {
    return listOf(
            LocationData(43.21123, 32.67643),
            LocationData(43.21123, 32.67643)
    )
}
```